# What is the meaning of "take something out of the trunk"?

Tags: meaning

> He claimed to find the atmosphere vital and creatively invigorating. Perhaps there was something to this: he had taken his languishing novel **out of the trunk** for the first time in nearly a year.
>
> *It* by Stephen King

Could you guys tell what he meant by saying that the novel got taken out of the **trunk**? Is this some kind of idiom?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Have you looked up the [different meanings of _trunk_?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trunk)

Comment: I'm guessing it's literal, and the novel was in a trunk.

Comment: Thank you @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_, I saw that it could be a sort of box, but thought that maybe it was used in a metaphorical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be interpreted several different ways.  First off, we can presumably ignore the possibility that it's referring to the main stem of a tree.

But in the US it could be referring to what the British refer to as the "boot" of a car, where car tools and luggage are stored. The other common usage (both in the US and the UK) is to refer to a large storage container used for clothes, and often kept in a closet or attic or such.

This latter definition is probably the closest fit to King's usage, but one should understand that the term may be used figuratively.  Eg, King may consider a particular corner of his mind to be a "trunk" where he accumulates ideas for novels.

Comment: +1 for " but one should understand that the term may be used figuratively. Eg, King may consider a particular corner of his mind to be a "trunk" where he accumulates ideas for novels." Not  a lot of people would understand that.

Comment: The first meaning that came to mind when I read the passage was *dusted off*,

Comment: I think you'd have to judge if the character was likely to own a literal travelling trunk in his attic; I believe the characters in It are possibly a bit young to have trunks, but I'm not sure exactly how old you would have to be to have one, and maybe it's commoner in Maine. This question seems to be more literary analysis than meaning of English words, though.

Comment: @StuartF -- It would not be surprising if a child had a trunk in the attic containing old gifts, memorabilia from his grandparents, etc.

Comment: A trunk can be a big suitcase. Given that the subject arrived to town for a 3-week stay and never left, that’s a possible interpretation.